# Add Blank Space between SVGs

Tags: html, svg, padding

I want to display 3 SVGs in a horizontal row in a div, with say 5px blank space between without changing the SVG at all.

Padding and Margin do not work, at least not reliably for svgs, so please what else could I do to achieve this?

Comment: Wrap the `svg` in a `<div>` and apply css to that.

Comment: Why did I not think of that! I tried putting divs between the svgs but that was messy. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make use of  `letter-spacing:`? This is one example of what you may be looking for.

```css
 div{
 text-align:center;
 letter-spacing:-10px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="RED" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="GREEN" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="BLUE" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 
 </div>
```

Comment: There appears to be no spacing between the svg's. The apparent spacing is within the svg (80px circle in 100px svg)